# Ionic 4 both sides menu - open specific menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

How can i open specific menu Ionic 4 double side menu?
for example:

```
<ion-menu #menuA menuId="menuA" side="start">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
        <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu #menuB menuId="menuB" side="end" type="push">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
      <ion-title>End Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
        <ion-item>
          zxzxz
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

when i click on a toolbar button, it always opens left side menu.
any ideas?
Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

From Docs [ https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu/ ]

You can use the MenuController to open menus on click with functions like so

html

```
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu side="end" type="push">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
      <ion-title>End Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

in TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-example.css'],
})
export class MenuExample {

constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }

  openFirst() {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'first');  // replace with MenuA for your case
    this.menu.open('first');
  }

  openEnd() {
    this.menu.open('end'); //replace with MenuB
  }
}
```

Comment: well it ain't working, i have tries this code and ionic docs reference and not success: event click on toolbar button A & event click on toolbar button B opening only first menu

Comment: can you share the toolbar code in html and the corresponding ts? may be you are missing something. cant debug from the given data

Comment: No need of so much code. Add ```menuId``` on all the available menus and then u can use ```ion-menu-button``` with ```menu=<menuId>``` and that button will be automatically mapped to that menu. If u want to use custom button, put that button in ```ion-menu-toggle``` and angain use the ```menu=<menuId>``` to toggle the menu. Use @DhananjaiPai's method if you want to open different menus with same button based on some logic.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with #Dhananjai Pai 's answer above. Would comment if I could. Just to clarify. As far as I can tell, you can't rely on the menuId and menu alone. As you show, you need to explicitly enable the menu you want.

In your ts file:

```
import { LoadingController, MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  openMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'menuA')
    .then(myMenu => {
      // console.log(myMenu);
      this.menuCtrl.open('menuA');
    });
  }
```

Then in your template:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <!--ion-menu-button autoHide="false" menu="master"></ion-menu-button-->
      <ion-button (click)="openMenu()">
        <ion-icon name="menu" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>My Devices</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

So, you don't need to use the ion-menu-button if you don't want to. This can easily be extended to use other menus (using their menuId), both in the same page, and in other pages. The key is just to enable the one you want programmatically, before you try and open it! This works fine in Ionic 4.